# ¿Como implemento la funcion de "presione cualquier tecla para continuar en C++?

Tags: c++

Hola estoy usando Microsoft Visual Studio para hacer un programa que te pregunte como se dicen algunas palabras en ingles, pero al principio quiero implementar un "presione cualquier tecla para continuar" y que siga a la siguiente linea.

Comment: podrias mirar el [tour] para saber como funcionamos? aparte, siempre agrega el codigo que intentaste y no funciono. Y si lo solucionaste, poner una respuesta que diga como se soluciona tambien es valido en este sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando visual studio, estas en windows. Asi que te invito a lo siguiente:

1. Abre una terminal
2. Escribe `pause` y dale enter

Si eso es lo que esperas, puedes poner en tu programa una llamada a ese comando con la función `system` de `cstdlib`

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hola Mundo\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Si quieres que funcione en otras plataformas, otra opcion seria hacerlo asi:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hola Mundo\n";
    std::cout << "Precione enter para continuar ... ";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Con la unica desventaja de que solo funciona si concrecionan enter, pero con la ventaja de que es multiplataforma.